# Illustrator - prepare logo with blur effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blur

My client wish was a logo with blur effect (as TATE Modern for example). Now I need to prepare all kind of files to deliver with small CI. 
The issue is, that logo doesn't scale properly.
So the question is: should I change all blured element with "Expand Appearance" or "Rasterize" or leave blur as it is (last - I don't think so)?

thanks for help!

Comment: What is "Small Cl"?

Answer (score 1):

While vector file formats today *do* support 'live' effects like blur, I don't think I'd rely on them quite yet. As such, yes, you do want to rasterize the effect so you have control.

So keep the illustrator version, for sure, but then rasterize out versions at the sizes you need.

As for the Tate, note that they don't have 'a logo' but rather a logo system. For example, the blur takes on a bunch of various forms:

[image]

And in some instances, they use a halftone, which could be turned into a vector fairly easily:

[image]

It's a rather clever--and actually complex--identity system.

Comment: I hit enter to quick ;)
I knew about raster /halftone version of Tate logo, but my concern is the blurred one. I know (now :) how to deal with this blurred parts, but i don't know if other users , find it easy to scale. I will do as you say - rasterize blur in large size and exportt files, but i leave non-rasterized also (eps ai) and write warning in a spectification, that changing size must be  taken with special attention. I think this is some resonable idea?

Comment: @syd yes, that's reasonable. You're definitely going to need to write some brand guidelines to show people how to use the logo at different sizes.